# Como trabalhar com lock em registros SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concorrência

Estou estudando melhor prática para trabalhar com `lock` de registros.

O que quero dizer é, tenho varias tabelas que podem ser acessadas por vários usuários simultaneamente, porém caso algum tenta-se editar o registro, para os outros este registro deveria estar bloqueado para edição.

Vi que algumas pessoas fazem tipo de um semáforo na própria tabela, colocam uma coluna chamada `editar` (por exemplo) e quando o usuário clicar no botão editar, ele seta essa coluna para 1, portanto quando o outro usuário for tentar editar podemos fazer uma regra `if` para tal.

Porém, também, vi que existem lock's no SQL Server, não seria melhor trabalhar com esse tipo de `lock`?

Afinal, existe um modelo que o pessoal utiliza para realizar essa função? Penso nisso pois acredito que todo software que seja para múltiplos usuários seja imprescindível algo como isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se for isso mesmo realmente é melhor usar `LOCK`. Mas esse mecanismo muito raramente deve ser usado.

O normal não é querer que fique travado. Ele pode ficar travado por horas, dias, não é o que se deseja.

Em geral não precisa fazer qualquer coisa. Se depende de dado editado de forma simples basta deixar gravar. Quem gravar por último terá a sua informação fixada. Isso ocorreria igual se não fosse concorrente e sim sequencial. Obviamente não pode gravar o que não foi alterado. Esse é um cuidado básico que muita gente não faz, mas deveria fazer. Se falhar nisso o dado não alterado irá se sobrepor ao alterado por outro usuário e não é o desejado, porque reverterá o que o outro usuário fez, sem ser o desejado.

Há casos que isso é mais complicado. Se for uma quantidade de estoque por exemplo, não pode só sobrepor o valor, porque ele pode ter sido alterado de forma que afetou a sua alteração. Em geral esse tipo de dado não é simplesmente editado, ele á alterado de forma controlada pela aplicação. Então no momento de gravar tem que fazer uma nova leitura do dado e gravar a atualização, isso provavelmente ocorrerá muito rápido, em geral abaixo de um milissegundo e de forma transacional (atômica). Já vi muito prejuízo porque o programador não faz isso. Aí a solução da pessoa é ser pessimista e travar tudo. Muito problema de performance é por causa disso.

Há casos que são mais complicados ainda. Outras estratégias podem caber. Uma delas é usar o `LOCK`, mas de forma bem rápida, não durante todo o processo de edição.

Até há como [configurar as transações com o grau de isolamento que deseja](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15). `READ COMMITTED` é o padrão e normalmente é o ideal. Algumas pessoas ficam tentadas a usar outros níveis para ficar mais garantido, mas isso pode travar as transações mais tempo que o desejado. Afinal isso no fundo é um tipo de *lock*. Usando isso corretamente estará seguro.

É fácil as pessoas usarem essas coisas incorretamente e criarem um [*deadlock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

A maioria das pessoas não entendem o funcionamento dos bancos de dados. Ou fazem aplicações muitos simples que independem ou tem pouca concorrência (que nem ocorre efetivamente), ou as pessoas deixam os problemas ocorrerem, eles são raros. Alguns até acertam por coincidência.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: perfeito, mas por exemplo, se quiser evitar que um registro que esteja sendo editado, seja apresentado para algum outro usuário, então o uso de lock ficaria justificado? a utilização de uma coluna somente para representar se esta em edição ou não, é fora de questão? digo isso seria uma gambiarra?

Comment: Nesse raro caso, seria sim. Particularmente eu não usaria outro mecanismo. Mas depende do caso. Pode ter uma justificativa para fazer. Em tudo pode ser útil se for bem justificado. O problema é fazer porque outro já fez antes e não entender o motivo. Tudo que sabia porque está fazendo, domina todas nuances dificilmente pode ser considerado gambiarra. Claro que o motivo não poder "não sei fazer de outro jeito", "não tenho tempo de fazer certo", etc. :) É possível que um campo assim seja útil. è possível que causa problemas que a pessoa nem percebeu, como faltar liberação. O `lock` é bem pensado

Answer (score 2):

Usar lock é pedir para se incomodar. A solução realmente decente vai exigir colaboração entre banco de dados e aplicação. Uma ideia:

1) Deve haver uma coluna timestamp que seja atualizada no insert e em todo update. Pelo menos o MySQL tem coluna TIMESTAMP que pode ser configurada para se atualizar sozinha a cada update, então até aqui é esforço zero do lado do aplicativo.

2) Ao iniciar a edição da linha, esse timestamp é lido (junto com os demais dados).

3) Antes de gravar a linha, o timestamp é lido novamente do banco. Se não bater com o timestamp lido no passo 2, não grava e avisa o usuário do conflito.

Poderia até mostrar quais colunas foram alteradas por outra pessoa, oferecer resolução de conflito, fazer merge das alterações se elas acontecem em colunas diferentes, etc.

4) A segunda leitura e a gravação final devem ocorrer dentro de uma mesma transação, para o caso (improvável) de um race condition, de dois tentarem gravar exatamente ao mesmo tempo.

5) O aplicativo deve lidar com a falha da transação, ou abortando a edição, ou voltando ao passo 3.

Answer (score -2):

Acho que a melhor maneira caso seja realmente necessário esse controle, seria criar em cada tabela 3 campos, EDIT_USER_ID, FG_LOCK, EDIT_TIMESTAMP.

E o sistema poderia tem uma variavel global de tempo máximo de edição, tipo Edit_Time = 10 minutos.

Se user 1 iniciar edição, o sistema registra os três campos. Se mais ninguem acessar, ao executar update se o EDIT_USER_ID for o mesmo do user salva.

Porém, se o user 2 tentar acessar antes do 10 minutos, o sistema avisará que o user 1 está editando, e que em:

(Edit_Time - (Timestamp user2 - Timestamp user 1))
(10 - (10:03 - 10:00)) => 10 - 3 = 7
7 minutos ele poderá acessar o registro.

Se o user 1 finalizar antes tudo bem, mas se passar dos 10 minutos, e o user 2 pedir edição, o EDIT_USER_ID e EDIT_TIMESTAMP são atualizados, e o user 1 não mais poderá concluir o update, recebendo uma mensagem de alerta, para editar novamente quando tentar salvar.

Desse jeito não corremos o risco de ter um registro LOCKED, porque depois de 10 minutos o registro pode ser acessado mesmo que esteja com o FG_LOCK=True.

Abraço.